# Migrate nodes with special characters in title

Tags: 8, nodes, migrations

Given a source's title like

```
This "cool" & "neat" article's title has HTML entities
```

, is creating a title of

```
This &quot;cool&quot; &amp; &quot;neat&quot; article&#39;s title has
HTML entities
```

Must I create a process plugin to handle this?
My migration yml looks somewhat like this:

```
...
source:
...
    -
      name: title
      label: 'Title'
      selector: title
...
process:
  title: title
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you will have to define a custom process plugin to do this - I can't find any plugin for it on [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/list-of-process-plugins-provided-by-migrate-plus) or [this](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/api/migrate-api/migrate-process-plugins/list-of-core-migrate-process-plugins) page.

There is a PHP function called `htmlspecialchars_decode`, which decodes all HTML special character entities, which you can probably use. It takes in a string and returns the decoded string. We also need to pass it the ENT_QUOTES flag for it to convert both double and single quotes.

So you could probably do something like:

```
namespace Drupal\YOUR_MODULE\Plugin\migrate\process;

use Drupal\migrate\MigrateExecutableInterface;
use Drupal\migrate\ProcessPluginBase;
use Drupal\migrate\Row;

/**
 * Decode HTML entities.
 * 
 * @MigrateProcessPlugin(
 *   id = "decode_html_entities"
 * )
 */
class DecodeHtmlEntityString extends ProcessPluginBase {

  public function transform(string $value, MigrateExecutableInterface $migrate_executable, Row $row, $destination_property) {
    return htmlspecialchars_decode($value, ENT_QUOTES);
  }

}
```

Comment: Thank you Victor F. I ended up implementing a process plugin like yours above. It works perfect but I was surprised that I had to do this step.

Answer (score 0):

I solved that with callable plugin:

```
process:
  title:
    source:
      - g_title
      - ENT_QUOTES
    plugin: callback
    callable: htmlspecialchars_decode
    unpack_source: true
```